# Static IP address on CentOS 7

Tags: ip, centos7, static-ip

I just installed CentOS minimal and now I am struggling to give my machine a fixed IP address. This is my `ifcfg-ens32` file:

```
DEVICE="ens32"
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO=static
IP_ADDR="192.168.0.243"
NETMASK="255.255.252.0"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT="yes"
NAME="System ens32"
GATEWAY="192.168.0.1"
HWADDR="00:0C:29:7B:28:24"
```

when I `systemctl restart network.service`, I do get to see it enables the interface, but when I run `ip a`, that interface does not have an IP address.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to include the output of `ip a`.

Comment: Just write IPADDR instead of IP_ADDR in your config file

Comment: @AntonMakovetsky could you make that an answer? That was indeed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write IPADDR instead of IP_ADDR in your config file

Answer (score 0):

As Anton already said, replace `IP_ADDR` with `IPADDR`. Also, make sure `NetworkManager` is not working:

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager
systemctl disable NetworkManager
ps auxww | grep NetworkManager
kill <pid> # in case there's any process running
```

and then

`systemctl restart network`